# Confusion related to node.js code

Tags: node.js

I found this code where it says that I can run some db queries asynchronously

```
var queries = [];


for (var i=0;i <1; i++) {
  queries.push((function(j){
    return function(callback) {
      collection.find(
    {value:"1"},

    function(err_positive, result_positive) {
       result_positive.count(function(err, count){
         console.log("Total matches: " + count);
         positives[j] = count;          
         callback();
       });
    }

      );
    }
  })(i));
}

async.parallel(queries, function(){
  // do the work with the results
}
```

I didn't get the part what is callback function how is it defined ? second in the queries.push, it is passing the function(j) what is j in this and what is this (i) for

```
queries.push((function(j){})(i));
```

I am totally confused how this code is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is preparing an array of nearly-identical functions as `tasks` for [`async.parallel()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel).

After the loop, given it only iterates once currently, `queries` would be similar to:

```
var queries = [
    function (callback) {
        collection.find(
            // etc.
        );
    }
];
```

And, for each additional iteration, a new `function (callback) { ... }` would be added.

> what is callback function how is it defined ?

`callback` is just a named argument for each of the functions. Its value will be defined by `async.parallel()` as another `function` which, when called, allows `async` to know when each of the tasks has completed.

> second in the queries.push, it is passing the function(j) what is j in this and what is this (i) for
>
> ```
> queries.push((function(j){})(i));
> ```

The `(function(j){})(i)` is an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) with `j` as a named argument, it's called immediately with `i` a passed argument, and returns a new `function (callback) {}` to be `push`ed onto `queries`:

```
queries.push(
    (function (j) {
        return function (callback) {
            // etc.
        };
    })(i)
);
```

The purpose of the IIFE is to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) -- a lexical scope with local variables that is "*stuck*" to any `function`s also defined within the scope. This allows each `function (callback) {}` to have its own `j` with a single value of `i` (since `i` will continue to change value as the `for` loop continues).

Answer (score 0):

Callback is one of the coolest features. Callback is just another normal function. You can actually pass a function itself as a parameter in another function. 
Say function foo() does something. You may want to execute something else right after foo() is done executing. So, in order to achieve this, you define a function bar() and pass this function as a parameter to function foo()!

```
function foo(callback){
  // do something
  callback();
}

function bar(){
  // do something else
}

foo(bar());
//here we can see that a function itself is being passed as a param to function foo.
```

For more understanding [here](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4)'s the right link.

And

```
queries.push((function(j){})(i));
```

in javascript, this is another way of calling a function.

```
function(){
// do something.
}();
```

You don't actually need to define a function name and it can be called directly without a name. You can even pass params to it.

```
function(a){
alert(a)'
}(10);
```